# Java WindowsBuilder application compiles with a terminated message

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am attempting to compile the code(shown below) in my Eclipse Neon 2 IDE running the 8.121 JRE. I have created a SWT Designer Project with a Swing Designer Application window. When I run the program **I do not see the blank application**, (but I see my test console output message
[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzj7d.png)
). I wanted to know if someone could tell me what is happening with my eclipse software? I reinstalled the software, and I tried many other solutions. I have done hours of researched, but I still do not understand why this is occurring? (SideNote: I am thinking of a time of when I coded in C++ this type of error occured aswell when I tried to make a console application I used 
    System("PAUSE") 
to solve that problem)

```
package test;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class test {

private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                test window = new test();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public test() {
    System.out.println("Test");
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }

 }
```

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hi, I am sure the code works correctly the problem is when I try to run it, eclipse will not show me the blank application. For example If I was to add a button and run the program, I cannot see the application to click the button.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hi Again, I believe I solved my problem. Instead Of creating a WindowBuilder->SWT Designer->SWT/Jface Java project I created a normal java project and added an Application Window file. Now with that I can see my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I was having was I created a

```
WindowBuilder->SWT Designer->SWT/Jface
```

Java project. So when I went to compile the Application Window file it did not show the application.

To solve the issue I just created a normal Java project and I added the Application Window file. So just make sure your file types and project types are correct for compilation of a program.

Comment: `SWT/JFace` is for SWT applications which are not the same as Swing.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.